# Change x axis labeling independent of x values?

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, axis-labels

Imagine I am plotting e.g. this:

```
plot(1:1500,1:1500)
```

This will look like the image below, with the x axis starting at 0 and going up to 1500.

Now I don't want to have that labeling, but instead the x axis labeling shall start with e.g. 1 and then end at 151 (increase by 1/10 for every point on the x axis, additionally an offset of 1).

I just want to change the labeling of the x axis, I don't want to change the x input vector to the plot function nor do I want to plot other points. I just want the x labeling to start at a different offset and increase in another step size, independent of the x values passed to the plot function.

Is that possible? How? It would make some things easier for me. Thanks for any hint!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could customize the tick marks using the XTick and XTickLabel [axis properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html).

Example:

```
x = 1:7;
y = rand(size(x));
plot(x,y)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',{'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'})
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, the XTickLabel property seems to be useful to me, as I could generate all the values for it. I am still wondering if it's possible do directly set something like xAxisOffset=1, xAxisStepsize=1/10, so that I don't have to build a full vector. But if I don't understand the properties wrong, there is nothing like that ):

Comment: @stean.at.wpf: not explicitly. `XTick` allows to specify where MATLAB shows tick marks. `XTickLabel` lets you customize the label at those locations. Note that once you manually set them, you no longer get the `auto` mode (try `plot(1:100)` then resize the figure and see how it adjust the tick marks according to the width)

Comment: @Amro: maybe I could change my example. What are the exact values you want on your x-axis. Is it `1:1/10:151` ? Also how frequently show you show them, N-values equally spaced?

Comment: Amro, for me it works quite well using XTickLabel, so I selected your answer as the correct one :-) (I just put seomthing like 1:1/10:151 as input to XTickLabel and leave the frequency of showing the label to Matlab, that's quite ok).